# Pokemon Go. Permanent ban?

Tags: pokemon-go

I tried to spoof my GPS location on pokemon Go but it didn't work. I know I shouldn't have but I can't afford Internet on my phone (dunno how to say it but I don't have data except with wifi) so I tried. Anyway after I tried it kept saying: "location not found". I couldn't play because of that so I thought it must have been a soft ban so I let it sit. After a week I tried again and it said the same thing. I tried uninstalling the app and then downloading it again. Didn't work. Also tried a different account. Same thing. What is that? They're trying to keep me from ever playing again?

Comment: You do the crime you do the time

Comment: Yeahh I know that but I don't think that's normal?

Comment: If you tried a different account and it still doesn't work then it's most likely something to do with your device.

Comment: @Virusbomb that's what I thought but wanted to make sure.. still weird my phone works well and is new-ish

Comment: Depending on what sort of phone you have, check your location settings. Some (Samsung Galaxy series for example) have multiple accuracy levels, which use 1 or more of your devices functionalities to discern your location (GPS, Wifi, and Mobile Data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to unmock the gps location... Go to settings,go to about device, click build number 8 times to unlock developer options, go back to settings, go to developer options, unclick mock gps location

Comment: Thank you so much it finally worked. Had totally forgotten about that

Answer (score 1):

When I have fake GPS running on my phone Pokemon Go says

> "Not able to locate"
>   (Translated from German)

Re-logging in doesn't help, But when I switch off Fake GPS I´m properly located by my phones GPS.

Maybe try to restart your device, not set any fake location and get outside (or to a place with as good GPS Signal as possible that is still in your Wifi range). and try to start Pokemon Go where you are. You wont be banned for that as a ban is only applied when you interact with a Pokestop (spin), a Pokemon (throw a ball) or a Gym (attack and maybe deposit... I haven't tried)

If your GPS doenst work properly you can download GSP test and clear agps and then update agps again. For a freind of mine who wasnt able to be located with his s4 mini this worked for him.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Niantic has taken a hardline stance on cheating. Whether you cheated for legitimate reasons or not is irrelevant. The ban is likely permanent.

I can't stand cheaters. I get gyms sniped by cheaters all the time. Sorry, but I have no sympathy.

Comment: Hmm, how can you tell they cheated?

Comment: Sorry if I offended you. I was trying to play this game wich is all my childhood. But I unfortunately cannot afford what everyone seems to have. I have 3 part time Jobs and I'm studying. Sorry if I can't pay everything like you

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry bro you are not banned, it's the recent update thats doing this and you are not the only one experiencing this.

Theres a solution to fix that, you can try login with another phone, however, if you dont have another phone you will need to login with pokemon trainers club. once thats complete logout from poke trainer club and login with your gmail account, then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a device ban. Have you tried with another device? If its working with another device and you don't afford to buy a new one, try to unlock your device id.but i dont highly recommend this route.